# Unable to execute parameterized SQL using Python and SQL Server

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I am trying to run a stored procedure with numerous parameters to it. To do that I am using `pyodbc` library and its `cursor.execute` function.

Following is the query I am trying to execute:

```
executionStr = "EXEC ? @ImportJSON= ?, ?=?, ?=?, ?=?",procName, data, param1, param1Value, param2, param2Value, param3, param3Value
```

When I run the query it gives me an error

> TypeError: The first argument to execute must be a string or unicode
> query.

When I try and run the query as following it executes successfully and I can see data going in.

```
executionStr = "EXEC "+procName+" @ImportJSON='"+data+"', "+param1+"='"+param1Value+"' , "+param2+"='"+param2Value+"' , "+param3+"='"+param3Value+"';"
```

I am trying to run the query in the previous format so that I protect my code from SQL Injection.

I also tried to run the query using parameters as follows but gives the same error:

```
preexe = "EXEC ? @ImportJSON= ?, "+param1+"=?, "+param2+"=?, "+param3+"=?"
procedure_cursor.execute(preexe,(procName, data, param1Value, param2Value, param3Value))
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong or where I am going wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last attempt was on the right track, but parameters can only be used to pass data **values** (e.g., strings, numbers, dates, etc.), not database object **names** (e.g., table names, column names, *stored procedure names*, etc.). Therefore, you'll need to do something like this:

```py
preexe = f"EXEC {procName} @ImportJSON= ?, {param1}=?, {param2}=?, {param3}=?"
procedure_cursor.execute(preexe, (data, param1Value, param2Value, param3Value))
```

This does not pose a significant risk of SQL Injection provided that your code has complete control over the values of `procName`, `param1`, `param2`, and `param3`.

Comment: Thank you Gord. It worked!

Thank you for letting me know the difference between data values and object names.